# How to Search for two separate parameters in a SQL statement in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sqlite, parameters

I'm trying to select movies from a database and I'm trying to make sure that the `IsRented` value is `0` (bit statement). The user types in the `MovieID` being a integer value and if the user enters a `MovieId` with the `IsRented=1`, it should throw an error.

```
private void AddToCartButon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int movieid;

        bool result = Int32.TryParse(MovieIDTextBox.Text, out movieid);

        if (result)
        {
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from Movies where IsRented=0", conn);
            conn.Open();
            SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr.Read() == true)
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand search = new SQLiteCommand("select * from Movies where MovieID LIKE @id", conn))
                {
                    search.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", movieid);

                    var DataTable = new DataTable();
                    var dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(search);
                    dataAdapter.Fill(DataTable);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable;
                }

                using (SQLiteCommand update = new SQLiteCommand("update Movies set IsRented=@rented where MovieID like @id", conn))
                {
                    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", movieid);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Currently your code tries to fetch a list of every movie that's not rented, and if there's at least one row (`.Read() = true`) tries to fetch the movie matching the ID provided. But why are you doing that first query? Isn't it enough to check the IsRented field from the row returned by the second query? Presumably you want to distinguish between "movie not found" and "movie found but currently rented out".

Comment: plz include the error/exception to yr question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your SELECT queries return a set of rows, but these sets are independent.

You have to check the `IsRented` value of the row that you are searching:

```
using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT IsRented FROM Movies WHERE MoveID LIKE @ID", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", movieid);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (!reader.Read())
        {
            // movie not found
        }
        else if (reader.GetBoolean(0))
        {
            // is rented
        }
        else
        {
            // not yet rented
        }
    }
}
```